# Pandas dataframe narrow to wide with pivot table no aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains the `iris` dataset.  I want to subset this dataframe to only include `sepal_length` and `species`, and then reshape it so that the columns are the unique values for `species` and the values are the values for that species.

```
# load data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

head(df)
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
|    | sepal_length  | sepal_width  | petal_length  | petal_width  | species |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
| 0  |          5.1  |         3.5  |          1.4  |         0.2  | setosa  |
| 1  |          4.9  |         3.0  |          1.4  |         0.2  | setosa  |
| 2  |          4.7  |         3.2  |          1.3  |         0.2  | setosa  |
| 3  |          4.6  |         3.1  |          1.5  |         0.2  | setosa  |
| 4  |          5.0  |         3.6  |          1.4  |         0.2  | setosa  |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+
```

I can do this is I take the data out of Pandas as use a dictionary to reshape the data, but I can't figure out how to do it within pandas.

```
data = df.to_dict('records')

e = {}
for line in data:
    e[line['species']] = []

for line in data:
    e[line['species']].append(line['sepal_length'])

new = pd.DataFrame(e)
```

This is what I want to end up with:

```
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
|    | setosa  | versicolor  | virginica |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 0  |    5.1  |        7.0  |       6.3 |
| 1  |    4.9  |        6.4  |       5.8 |
| 2  |    4.7  |        6.9  |       7.1 |
| 3  |    4.6  |        5.5  |       6.3 |
| 4  |    5.0  |        6.5  |       6.5 |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

I've tried using `pd.crosstab(df['sepal_length'], df['species'])` but that doesn't get me what I want.  I've also tried using `df.pivot_table('sepal_length', columns='species')` and that also isn't it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does the initial dataframe look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`grouby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) on `species` col and set index, then use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) instead of [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) which does not requires an `agg` func.

```
df1 = df.set_index(df.groupby('species').cumcount())

df1 = df1.pivot(columns='species', values='sepal_length').rename_axis(None,axis=1)

print (df1)

   setosa  versicolor  virginica
0     5.1         7.0        6.3
1     4.9         6.4        5.8
2     4.7         6.9        7.1
3     4.6         5.5        6.3
4     5.0         6.5        6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do will take a few steps. (The code below assumes use of the standard ["Iris dataset"](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/d546eaee765268bf2f487608c537c05e22e4b221/iris.csv)).

1. First, let's subset your `DataFrame` by only the columns we need.

   ```
   df_subset = df[['sepal_length','species']]
   ```
2. Next, use [`pandas.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) (intead of `pandas.pivot_table`) to convert your `DataFrame` from "long" to "flat".

   ```
   df_pivot = df_subset.pivot(columns='species',values='sepal_length')
   ```
3. Now, we're close to what you wanted but because your three `species` columns run along the same index, the pivoted `DataFrame` returns `NaN`s for two of the three columns for any given row. We can work around this by column-wise concatenating the `DataFrame` while re-indexing it. (Essentially creating three `DataFrames` - one for each species - and joining them along a new index). We can do this one of two ways:

   - The compact solution:

     ```
     names = ['setosa','versicolor','virginica']

     df_final = pd.concat(map(lambda name: df_pivot[name].dropna().reset_index().drop('index',axis=1), names), axis=1)
     ```
   - Which is equivalent to:

     ```
     df_final = pd.concat([
         df_pivot['setosa'].dropna().reset_index().drop('index',axis=1),
         df_pivot['versicolor'].dropna().reset_index().drop('index',axis=1),
         df_pivot['virginica'].dropna().reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)],axis=1)
     ```